# Basic Express route: what am I doing wrong?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying out node js and express. I have a basic web server with a route set up as follows:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(require('morgan'));
app.get('/api/beer', function(req, res) {
res.send("You found beer");
});
app.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log("ready to receive requests.");
});
```

When I start up the server using nodemon I see: "ready to receive requests."

However, if i then open up a browser window (Chrome) and navigate to

```
http://localhost:3000/api/beer/
```

I see "Waiting for localhost..." in the status bar for a long time followed by "No Data Received". I was expecting "You found beer".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure this is your code.  I run your code and get the expected result.

Comment: what does the node process output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't

```
app.use(require('morgan'));
```

be this instead?:

```
app.use(require('morgan')());
```

Otherwise, everything else looks fine to me.